# iOS UIStackView items to wrap content but have the items distributed to fill entire available space

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a UIStackView with varying height items.
The height of the items is determined by their content, i dont want to force it with a constraint.

I want the items to be spaced such that all the times take up the entire screen available.

What are the settings i need to set to make it work ?

Comment: Constrain the top and bottom of the stack view, and set Distribution: Equal spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple example...

Vertical Stack view with 3 multiline labels. Each time we tap anywhere, the labels will be re-filled with 1-to-8 lines of text, showing that the arranged subviews will determine their own heights:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The red dashed rectangle shows the frame of the stack view.

Here's the example code:

```
class LenaBruViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let stack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.distribution = .equalSpacing
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add 3 labels to the stack view
        for _ in 1...3 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.numberOfLines = 0
            // to make it easy to see the frames
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        // red dashed-outline view to show the stack view frame
        let stackOutlineView = DashedOutlineView()
        
        [stackOutlineView, stack].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain stack view 20-pts from all 4 sides
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // constrain outline view 1-pt around the stack view
            stackOutlineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.topAnchor, constant: -1.0),
            stackOutlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.leadingAnchor, constant: -1.0),
            stackOutlineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.trailingAnchor, constant: 1.0),
            stackOutlineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.bottomAnchor, constant: 1.0),

        ])
        
        fillLabels()
        
        // tap anywhere to re-fill the labels
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.fillLabels))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    @objc func fillLabels() -> Void {
        // set text of labels - from 1 to 8 lines
        let a: [Int] = Array(1...8).shuffled()
        for (v, n) in zip(stack.arrangedSubviews, a) {
            guard let lbl = v as? UILabel else { fatalError("This Demo should have only labels in the stack view!!") }
            lbl.text = ((1...n).map { "Line \($0)" }).joined(separator: "\n")
        }
    }
}

class DashedOutlineView: UIView {
    
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        shapeLayer = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [8,8]
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    }
}
```